# How can I load a single WFS vector feature where the user clicks the map on OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, wfs, editing

I am creating a web app that allows users to easily edit feature attributes as well as geometry. I have editing working by loading a WFS layer, but it slows the app to a crawl when there's more than a couple dozen features on the screen.

Instead of loading all of the features as vectors, **I want to display them as a raster layer, then when a feature is clicked, grab the associated vector for that feature**, in order to allow for editing. Has anyone done this before, or know of the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy to do.

1. Show your data as a WMS service.
2. When your user clicks on the map,get the id of the feature, either by using a WFS getfeature or WMS getfeatureInfo.
3. Once you get the unique id, create a vector layer with wfs Protocol, and a dynamically built CQL.

You will get just the selected feature in the WFS layer.

Comment: good answer, good timing. this was next on my list. I just finished doing something similar but by using latlon results from plugin leaflet.geosearch and cql call to geoserver. you make it sound easy, thanks

Comment: @geomajor56 Most things are conceptually very simple; It is the implementation that is the hard part.

Comment: Thanks Devdatta. I was thinking it is something along these lines. I got it implemented by using a Logical filter to filter the WFS layer by the clicked FeatureId.